# How cut characters from string and put it at the end- In shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to be able to do the following:

```
String1= "HELLO 3002_3322 3.2.1.log"
```

And get output like:

```
output = "3002_3322 3.2.1.log HELLO"
```

I know the command sed is able to do this but I need some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to know how to do it in sed? Are you only looking to move "HELLO" to the end?

Comment: Provide more details and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sed you can do:

```
sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Which outputs `3002_3322 3.2.1.log HELLO`.

**Explanation**

1. The first word is captured by 
   `\([^[:blank:]]*\)`
   The `\(\)` means I want to capture this group to use later. `[:blank:]` is a POSIX character class for whitespace characters. You can see the other POSIX character classes here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

The outer `[]` means match anyone of the characters, and the `^` means any character except those listed in the character class. Finally the `*` means any number of occurrences (including 0) of the previous character. So in total `[^[:blank:]]*` this means match a group of characters that are not whitespace, or the first word. We have to do this somewhat complicated regex because POSIX sed only supports BRE (basic regex) which is greedy matching, and to find the first word we want non-greedy matching.

2. `[[:blank:]]*`, as explained above, this means match a group of consecutive whitespaces.
3. `\(.*\)` This means capture the rest of the line. The `.` means any single character, so combined with the `*` it means match the rest of the characters.
4. For the replacement, the `\2 \1` means replace the pattern we matched with the 2nd capture group, a space, then the first capture group.

Comment: particularity here, `^` and  `$` are optionnal

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Could you kindly elaborate on the groups and syntax.  From my understanding, the first group grabs until the first blank space? and not too sure about the second group, specifically the :blank: part.

Comment: I have added more explanation, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**AWK**

`awk` is one tool to do something like that:

```
echo "HELLO 3002_3322 3.2.1.log" | awk '{print $2$3" "$1}'
```

What it does:

- `awk`, without delimiter flag of `-F` splits by whitespace sequences
- that means, HELLO 3002_3322 and 3.2.1.log will be seen
- HELLO is referred to by $1; 3002_3322 is $2 and so on
- we print $2, then $3 then one space, then $1

**SED**

I have a unpretty looking `sed` example for you:

```
echo "HELLO 3002_3322 3.2.1.log" | sed 's_\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)_\3 \2 \1_'
```

What it does:

- nomenclature is `s_<pattern>_<replacement>_`
- first `s` stands for substitute
- _ is the delimiter
- (.*) is paranthesis dot star parenthesis. That is the first group of characters we are asking sed to match. `.*` means match any sequence of characters or no characters at all. Ignore the `\` before `(` and `)` for now
- Notice the `\s` after the group. `\s` matches one space. So, we are asking sed to separate out `(.*)\s` - i.e. ()
- We repeat that to tell sed - (group1)(group2)(group3)
- First group's shorthand is \1, group2's shorthand is \2 etc.
- For replacement, we tell sed to arrange \3 (group3) first, then \2 (group2) and then \1 (group1)

`(` is a special character in sed. So we have to escape it by a forward slash. So, `(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)` becomes `\(.*\)\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)`. Oh so pretty!

Comment: Note that \s is not supported by POSIX sed and that you should use [[:blank:]] to denote whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+)(\s+)(.*)/\3\2\1/' file
```

Pattern match non-spaces, spaces and what is left and then use the remembered patterns (back references) in the replacement part of the substitution command.

N.B. The `-r` aurgument just removes the need for copius back slashes, so the same solution may be written as:

```
sed 's/^\(\S\S*\)\(\s\s*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file
```

This also removes the syntatic sugar of the the metacharacter `+` which means one or more of the preceeding pattern.

Further note, that `\S` and `\s` may be replaced by `[^[:space:]]` and `[[:space:]]` respectively. Leading to:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\)\([[:space:]][[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too (without awk or sed):

```
#!/bin/sh
String1="HELLO 3002_3322 3.2.1.log"
start="${String1%% *}"
end="${String1#* }"
output="$end $start"
echo "$output"
```

Or using `cut` (in Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
String1="HELLO 3002_3322 3.2.1.log"
rstr="$(echo "$String1" |cut -d" " -f1)"
output="${String1/$rstr /} $rstr"
echo "$output"
```